# Select Max value from a column , when multiple sessions access the same database

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a stored procedure , which selects max value from a column. I am retrieving the max value and after some computation , increment the max value with 1.This works fine , until multiple sessions access the same procedure at the same instant. In this case , all the sessions return the same value.

I need a way to stop the other sessions to retrieve max value of a column in SP , when one session is using it.

Please let me know a way to do this ?

I cannot use a sequence , because i need to start from a predefined value to go until a fixed value. This range is again conditionally computed.

Max Query is the below :

```
SELECT NVL(MAX(EMP_NBR),0)
INTO V_MAX_EMP_NO
FROM EMP
where emp_name like '%John%'
```

Comment: How many concurrent sessions are you expecting? How long does the computation take? If you can tolerate some waiting time, you can use SELECT...FOR UPDATE. It will lock the table.

Comment: I dont want to lock the entire table. Because a lot of updates , happen after my select max is done. I want to lock only max value selection part ? .Is that possible ?

Comment: You can use the technique described here http://rwijk.blogspot.nl/2008/01/sequence-within-parent.html, and use the predefined value + row_number() analytic function in a view.

Answer (score 2):

If you can deal with gaps in your values, you should use a [**sequence**](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_6015.htm) for this.

**Edit**

I'm afraid you will have to lock the whole table with your current constellation.

Something like this:

```
DECLARE
  v_emp_nbr        emp.emp_nbr%TYPE;
BEGIN
  LOCK TABLE emp IN SHARE MODE;

  SELECT NVL(MAX(emp_existing.emp_nbr),0) + 1
  INTO v_emp_nbr
  FROM emp emp_existing
  WHERE emp_existing.emp_name LIKE '%John%';

  INSERT INTO emp( emp_nbr, emp_name ) VALUES ( v_emp_nbr, 'John Doe' );
END;
/
```

Think again if you really need to calculate your `emp_nr` like this. You lock the whole table any time you insert a new record, and you cannot use an index on `emp_name` since you have a wildcard (`%`) at the beginning of your search term. Your query will get slower with every new entry you have.

We might be able to suggest a better solution if we knew why you need this.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I don't want to lock the entire table. Because a lot of updates , happen after my select max is done. I want to lock only max value selection part ? .Is that possible ?

Comment: Yes, as I said, handle this part in an autonomous transaction and you should be fine.

Comment: Suppose my Select Query to Retrieve max value of a column is returning  a result set of 4 records , and then out of the 4 , i am selecting the max value of a specific column , then will all the four records will be locked ?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand how exactly you determine your max value, could you edit your question to explain this, preferred by posting the relevant code?

Comment: Edited my answer, please check again.